# RegEx to remove number + space from cells with carriage-return data VBA

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have data in cells like

```
1  stuff
14 stuff2
9  stuff3
.
.
nn stufn
```

I need

```
stuff
stuff2
stuff3
.
.
stufn
```

I have

```
Sub test()
Dim r As Range

With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
  .Global = True
  .Pattern = "^\S* "

  For Each r In Selection
      r.value = .Replace(r.value, "")
  Next

 End With
End Sub
```

But it only removes the first instance in the string

```
stuff
14 stuff2
9  stuff3
.
.
nn stufn
```

How to remove all the numbers + space

Thanks

Comment: You should use `.Multiline = True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
.MultiLine = True
.Pattern = "^\S+ +"
```

The `.MultiLine = True` will make `^` match at the beginning of each line and  `+` will match 1+ spaces.

Answer (score -1):

as per your data example you could avoid regex and simply go:

```
Selection.Replace what:="*stuf", replacement:="stuf", lookAt:=xlPart
```